# Query causing Database lock problem (php/Mysql)

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

What is the issue with my query? When I execute, it lock the database for 5 to 10 minutes. Please help me to optimize this query.

```
SELECT 
    u.username, 
    u.email, 
    u.created_at, 
    p.firstname, 
    p.lastname, 
    p.address, 
    p.address_2, 
    p.city, 
    p.country, 
    p.state, 
    p.zip, 
    p.phone, 
    p.phone_2, 
    u.last_ip, 
    u.last_login_at, 
    u.auto_login, 
    u.registration_page,
    s.product_name
    FROM
    users AS u
        Left Join subscriptions AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
        Left Join profiles AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
    where u.registration_page='Chris_Cleanse' and
        u.id not in (select user_id from goal_sheets) and 
        u.id not in(select user_id from sheet_user_popup_not_adam) and 
        s.expired=TRUE ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.username, 
    u.email, 
    u.created_at, 
    p.firstname, 
    p.lastname, 
    p.address, 
    p.address_2, 
    p.city, 
    p.country, 
    p.state, 
    p.zip, 
    p.phone, 
    p.phone_2, 
    u.last_ip, 
    u.last_login_at, 
    u.auto_login, 
    u.registration_page,
    s.product_name
    FROM
    users AS u
        Left Join subscriptions AS s ON u.id = s.user_id
        Left Join profiles AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
        LEFT JOIN goal_sheets AS gs ON u.id = gs.user_id
        LEFT JOIN sheet_user_popup_not_adam AS supna ON u.id = supna.user_id
    where u.registration_page='Chris_Cleanse' and
        s.expired=TRUE and
        gs.user_id IS NULL and
        supna.user_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY u.id DESC
```

You can transform the subqueries into left joins and check for `IS NULL` in `where` conditions. MySQL performs better on joins than on subqueries.

Have you set appropriate indexes on your tables? Otherwise this should be done too. (Indexes on `subscriptions.user_id`, `profiles.user_id`, `goal_sheets.user_id` and `sheet_user_popup_not_adam.user_id` should exist as minimum.)